# How to get all values after submit - not touched fields included

Tags: react-final-form

I need to get all values in onSubmit method, not only dirty fields.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form'

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Form onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}>
    {({ form: { submit } }) => (
      <>
        <Field name="street" component="input" placeholder="street" />
        <Field name="city" component="input" placeholder="city" />
        <Field name="state" component="input" placeholder="state" />
        <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
      </>
    )}
  </Form>
)

export default App
```

Actual result:
`{street: "A", city: "B"}`

Expected result:
`{street: "A", city: "B", state: null}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Form [treats `''` and `undefined` as more or less equivalent](https://github.com/final-form/final-form/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-does--final-form-set-my--field-value-to-undefined).

You'll need to provide an `initialValues={{ street: null, city: null, state: null }}` to get your expected result. However, if the user touches field, changes the value, and then changes it back to empty, the `street` key will be deleted from the form values (see above link). You *could* get around that by providing a `parse={v => v}` [to cancel the normal `''`-to-`undefined` conversion](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#parse-value-any-name-string--any).

Hope that helps?